# How to test Binary Tree using Junit?

Tags: java, junit, binary-tree

How do I develop JUnit test for the `BinaryTree` class that I've written?

Please advise or provide examples so I can have better understand how to test binary tree in Junit.

```
package binaryTree;

import javax.xml.soap.Node;

public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements BTree<T> {
    private TreeNode root;
    Node current = (Node) root;
    @Override

    public void insert(T value) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(value);
            } else if (value.compareTo(value()) < 0) {
            root.getleft().insert(value);
            } else {
            root.right().insert(value);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public T value() {
        if (this.root != null) {
            return (T) this.root.value();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BTree<T> left() {
        if (this.root != null) {
            return this.root.getleft();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BTree<T> right() {
        if (this.root != null) {
            return this.root.right();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I provided a simple example testing a dummy `add` function. You need to import your `BinaryTree` class, and write test cases for that. That said, I think you need to clarify what you are asking: are you not sure about **how to test binary trees**, or about **how to write a simple JUnit test**. Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples are appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely read the docs in @tpitsch's post. But here's a simple example to get you started.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

// This test class contains two test methods
public class SimpleTest {

    private int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    @Test public void test1() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("@Test1");
        assertEquals(add(1, 1), 2);
    }

    @Test public void test2() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("@Test2");
        assertEquals(add(100, -30), 70);
    }
}
```

We're testing the function `add`.

Each function with the `@Test` annotation is a JUnit test method. Each test method is run as a separate JUnit test. Function names `test1()` and `test2()` are not important.

In a test method, you can place [assertions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) such as `assertEquals()` that make sure the `add` function is running as expected.